# Maximizing a Ratio/Percent

Tags: linear-programming, linearization, reformulation-linearization, cvxpy, disciplined-quasiconvex-programming

I'm using `cvxpy` to model a problem. Inside a very large and complex LP, I create two continuous, affine (unconstrained) expressions: $x$ and $y$. Due to how they are created, I know that $0\lt x \lt y \leq U$. Obviously: $x/y \lt 1$.

In my LP *objective*, how do I ***maximize*** the ratio $x/y$?

Things I tried:

- Maximizing `x*cp.inv_pos(y)` states my problem is non DCP (also if I try to minimize the inverse)
- I found various LP formulations for maximizing ratios (e.g. [here](http://lpsolve.sourceforge.net/5.5/ratio.htm) or [here](https://download.aimms.com/aimms/download/manuals/AIMMS3OM_LinearProgrammingTricks.pdf#page=8)) but these requires rewriting the *constraints* on all the terms in the expressions for $x$ - I have no idea how to do that with `cvxpy`.
  If this is the way to go then an example would be very helpful!

Comment: @Mason the measure I need to maximize needs to be a “unitless” proportion between 0-1 so that it it properly scaled with other measures in the objective.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CVXPY makes this easy to do, using its disciplined quasiconvex programming (DQCP) capability.

An example is provided at https://www.cvxpy.org/examples/dqcp/concave_fractional_function.html .  Fractional Linear programming, as you have, is a simple special case of this.

Comment: This works fine for a single ratio, but my objective is, unfortunately, an affine combination (weighted-sum) of such ratios.

Comment: You neglected to state that in your original question. Your newly state problem is a different problem. Perhaps you can provide the complete problem, with all constraints?

Comment: You're right. My original question was about ratios - which as you suggested I *can* maximize. However, I then realized that my true objective is a weighted-sum of ratios.
I can post that as a separate question if you prefer.

Comment: Yes, that would be better as a new question.